# Community Promotion Ads - 2017

Tags: discussion, community-ads

It is a bit late into this new year, being that we're already in the second month, but we are now cycling the Community Promotion Ads for 2017!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- interesting articles or findings for the curious
- cool Science Fiction or Fantasy events/conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/10564).

Answer (score 39):

[image: Worldbuilding Stack Exchange]

Comment: We're working on new art for this year.

Comment: Image updated to use the new design, see [this thread on WB meta](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/4398/6507) for information regarding the community's approval.

Answer (score 26):

[image: Visit Literature.SE!]

Comment: Mithrandir, @CreationEdge: I can't upvote this because the list reminds me of [Borges's classification of animals](http://wiki.c2.com/?BorgesClassificationOfAnimals). "Classic", "Comedy", and "Shakespeare" just aren't comparable categories. It's a nice idea, but it needs more work IMO. Remember, **we have a [meta post](http://meta.literature.stackexchange.com/q/395/17)** explicitly for designing ads for Literature. No need to jump the gun, at least until it's into public beta.

Comment: My comment above referred to the previous revision of this post. Now that it's been improved to a list of genres, I'm happy to upvote. (However, are we really going to have *two* different ads for Literature here?)

Comment: @Rand  -  the more the merrier, especially in case of pre-public beta

Comment: I deleted [mine](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/10571/31394). This ad is much better, and even more highly voted now.

Answer (score 26):

[image: There's a Blog?]

Comment: Shamelessly copied from [last year's post](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9389/70236) by AncientSwordRage

Comment: We have a blog?

Comment: Came here to post this, thanks for saving me the trouble!

Comment: @AncientSwordRage  -  I'm just working towards the meta badge :P

Answer (score 25):

[image: Movies & TV Stack Exchange]

Comment: As copied from [last year's ad](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/7955/23386).

Answer (score 21):

[image: Get Crafty on crafts.se!]

Comment: Same as last year's!

Answer (score 13):

[image: Active bounties]

Comment: No there aren't, there's 5, worth +450..?

Comment: @Edlothiad uhhhh that's what it says :P If one was brand new than maybe it took a bit to update, but that's what it says for me right now.

Comment: mine still says 4 and 350?

Comment: @Edlothiad http://imgur.com/a/Y2l4Y clear your cache

Comment: The picture isn't loading for me.

Comment: @Valorum the server has been spotty recently, if it stays down I'll delete the ad.

Comment: Wow, how does that ad thing work? That's nice!

Answer (score 13):

[image: Writers.SE]

Comment: I like writers.SE, but LCARS seems like a bit of a non-sequitur, IMHO.

Answer (score 10):

[image: Memory Alpha - Star Trek Canon Wiki]

Answer (score 9):

[image: Pottermore - The digital heart of the Wizarding World]

Comment: See also [the updated version](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/10592/43655) below.

Comment: Both versions are now above the threshold. Should we simply delete the older version here (like with the Literature.SE one above), or how do we go about it?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - People voted for both. I see no good reason to delete one or the other, not least because the older version (this one) is getting more clicks-throughs.

Comment: But does it make sense to have two different community ads to the same place? (I suspect the clickthroughs may be at least in part because this one sits higher on the page—once people reach the other one, they've already clicked through on this one, so there's no need to do it again. Also, where do you see clickthroughs? Is that a 20,000+ tool I don't know about or something?)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - It's on the [clickstats](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/ads/display/10564) page

Answer (score 9):

[image: Prepare to lose an hour of your life on TV Tropes]

Comment: Nooooo don't do this to us

Comment: @MissMonicaE - http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/main/tvtropeswillruinyourlife

Comment: @MissMonicaE - What you're like right now; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WWaLxFIVX1s

Comment: Needs a warning sign.

Comment: :)  Beautiful irony.

Comment: @SQB - Check the mouseover

Comment: I can't, I'm on mobile — no mouse.

Comment: @Valorum exactly!

Comment: The mouseover says "Prepare to lose an hour of your life".  That's very inaccurate, because you usually lose your whole rest of the day. See https://www.xkcd.com/609/ which says "all day", and TVTROPES WARNING http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BrowserNarcotic?from=Main.TabExplosion which says "hours of your day", and http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TVTropesWillRuinYourLife says "Some editors spend 7 hour+ periods just reading through the thousands of pages".

Answer (score 9):

[image: Need more Potter? Visit J.K. Rowling’s Pottermore.com for fresh Potter facts and fun! Updated regularly.]

Comment: Since Pottermore got an overhaul last year, I thought it was time our Pottermore Community Promotion Ad got one, too, reflecting the new layout of the site. This version builds on the [previous version](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/10572/43655) shown in Valorum’s answer on this page, put together by Slytherincess, SQB, and Richard; I’ve kept SQB’s brilliant motto and redone the graphics myself. (This was included [last year](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9448/43655) as well, but too late to garner much attention.)

Comment: To be honest, it might not even have been a bad approach to simply switch out the old image in the existing answer. In fact if this one goes through it's probably advisable for the older one to get dropped anyway. It's not like they really provide anything beyond each other.

Comment: @CahirMawrDyffrynæpCeallach It was meant to be a replacement for the other one; that one just got put up first both years.

Comment: Yeah, and I think you could probably just switch out the image instead of posting an entirely new answer (that would have to be voted for *and* that coexists with the old outdated ad).

Comment: @CahirMawrDyffrynæpCeallach I didn't want to steal people's votes and change the image into one that the eight people who'd voted for the old one already hadn't actually voted for… but I don't actually know what the proper way to deal with it is.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Personally, I'd just delete the other answer now that this one is over the threshold.

Comment: @Kevin - People voted for both. I see no good reason to delete one or the other.

Answer (score 8):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting

Answer (score 8):

[image: Find canon Star Wars information]

Comment: After [this bug report](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/10685/31394), I edited the tagline here from the generic "Tagline to show on mouseover" to "Find canon Star Wars information". Just FYI, so you can change it to a different tagline if you want.

Answer (score 8):

[image: Interested in Sindarin, Vulcan, or Dothraki?]

Answer (score 7):

[image: The J.R.R. Tolkien encyclopedia that anyone can edit.]

Comment: A quick design suggestion: it would look more balanced and maybe slightly easier to read if the text was inset from the sides by 20 pixels or so.

Comment: Yeah, though I'd go even a bit more, especially on the top, so that the T doesn't sit right up against the side. :)

Comment: @curiousdannii - Better?

Answer (score 6):

[image: Wookieepedia - The Star Wars Wiki]

Comment: But Wookieepedia isn't a reliable source. How about a link to the (canon) SW databank instead?

Comment: Per the instructional; "*interesting articles or findings for the curious*". Wookieepedia certainly fits that bill.

Comment: (For the record, I've upvoted your Memory Alpha ad as - in my experience - that's been a much more useful and reliable site.)

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Wookieepedia is *generally* reliable. I've not found more than a handful of errors. Memory Alpha tends to be more precise about referencing but has fewer examples and hence is likely to generate fewer questions as a result...

Comment: Back when I was regularly answering Star Wars questions, I received quite a few (justified) downvotes and criticisms for posting answers which cited nothing more than Wookieepedia. So I learned to use more canonical sources, like SW Databank or interviews or the TFA Visual Dictionary. (Not that I'm trying to teach my grandmother how to suck eggs here, just sharing my own experiences since you wanted reasons for downvotes.)

Answer (score 4):

[image: Matrixfans - Forums, Interviews, Trailers and Trivia]

Comment: Knocked something out, since there seem to be interest in this website, if not previous designs.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if the `matrixfans.net` text was black, instead of out-of-place looking black background? Otherwise, I find this ad superb!

Comment: @Gallifreyan It's meant to look like one of those labels with the raised letters that you used to find on old office equipment a lot. \*shrug\*

Comment: *shrug* never saw anything like it :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: The Lord of the Rings Wiki]

Comment: Please don't just drive-by downvote. If there's a specific reason you don't think the community would like this advert, please let me know.

Comment: I'm downvoting because LotR Wikia isn't a reliable source. Tolkien Gateway would be much better.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Again, I've found that the Gateway, although largely reliable, has a tendency to ignore sources that site-users might find interesting.

Comment: I suspect LotR Wikia is generally better-known and so more likely to come up in the average internet user's search engine results. So advertising Tolkien Gateway is more likely to show them something they didn't already know.

Comment: @Valorum and lotr.wikia has a tendency to make up utter garbage.