# Markup glitch: “Tagline to show on mouseover”

Tags: bug, status-completed, advertising

I just saw this ad:

[image: the actual ad image]

on a SF&F page (it was [here](//scifi.stackexchange.com/q/73349/30482), although I doubt that it matters). 
I moved my mouse pointer over it
and the text “Tagline to show on mouseover” appeared.

[image: screenshot from my screen]

Obviously that’s a template value that was meant to be replaced.

Browser is Internet Explorer 11.

Comment: Technically this might be [meta-tag:status-bydesign], since the tagline is exactly what it was set to be in the ad posted on meta. But I'm marking it [meta-tag:status-completed] because you found an issue that's been fixed, even if it was due to human error rather than anything wrong in the system.

Answer (score 5):

This is because the person who posted the ad on our [Community Promotion Ads](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10564/31394) page didn't include a proper tagline other than the generic one. Here's his post in edit mode:

[image: screenshot]

I just edited the tagline to "Find canon Star Wars information", so this is now fixed.