# Community Promotion Ads - 2018

Tags: discussion, community-ads

It's almost February in 2018, which isn't supposed to be the proper time to cycle these, but for this year it'll be once again, so we'll be refreshing the **Community Promotion Ads** for this year now!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- interesting articles or findings for the curious
- cool Science Fiction or Fantasy events/conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/11670).

Comment: Possibly worth asking people to give some indication whether downvotes are because they don't like the content (the site that you're trying to advertise) or because they don't like the presentation (the look/design/tagline of the advert).

Answer (score 15):

[image: There's a Blog?]

Comment: Shamelessly copied from [last year's post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10584/68872) by Gallifreyan

Comment: We have a blog?

Answer (score 11):

[image: Love to read? Visit Literature SE!]

Comment: Copied from [last year's post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10574/31394) by Mithrandir; designed by CreationEdge.

Comment: Recycled one but still my fav till now here ;)

Comment: @Erosennin Btw, do you guys have a nice image for promoting M&TV on other sites, which we could use here? (yes, I still recognise you despite the latest name change ;-) )

Comment: We are talking about it in screening room, you can help us out too ;)

Comment: I dropped an idea about what scifi can do there too.

Answer (score 9):

[image: Get Crafty on crafts.se!]

Comment: As this was one of the adverts that was chosen last year, it might be worth changing the words and imagery. There are no end of [great](https://i2.wp.com/www.tor.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/DoctorWhoScarf.jpg?fit=600%2C+9999&crop=0%2C0%2C100%2C700px&ssl=1) photos you could [use](https://i.pinimg.com/736x/28/37/98/28379852bd4db6ba9323b7a5b80d1afd--doctor-who-scarf-the-doctor.jpg) to illustrate the same scarf

Comment: @Valorum Those examples are overly grainy and don't fit easily within the aspect ratio we're required to use while still leaving room for text.

Comment: Those were merely examples

Comment: @Valorum I searched for some time when I originally made this for an image that fit the style, text, ratio, quality, etc. that I wanted to use.

Comment: Per the OP; "*It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.*" - You don't have to, obviously, but after a year of staring at the same advert it might be useful to at least change the tagline. Something like *"Help to knit the space-time continuum back together"*

Comment: @Valorum No. Sorry. I posted this one for a reason. If other people have suggestions they can make their own with their own time. If this isn't still good enough, it won't get upvoted and that's fine.

Comment: I'm afraid I've downvoted for the reasons above. The ad is over a year old and pretty tired.

Comment: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ Can't say I care. I was asked to repost this. Next time, provided there is one, I'll just redirect people to post it themselves, because this kind of commentary has been nothing more than an annoyance for me.

Answer (score 8):

[image: The J.R.R. Tolkien encyclopedia that anyone can edit.]

Answer (score 8):

[image: Worldbuilding Stack Exchange]

Comment: Copied from [last year](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10566/32756).

Comment: Woohoo I love this one! Additional comment removed, it's only been 1 year and I love it.

Comment: Nice ad! Do you have one for [writers.se] as well?

Comment: @Randal'Thor we'll work on one, thanks!

Comment: @Randal'Thor one of our members made [this](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11743/32756).

Answer (score 8):

[image: Space Exploration Stack Exchange]

Comment: I really dislike the squashing on this version. The pic needs to be recomposed, not just resized.

Comment: @RussellBorogove - I've resolved the squashing by cropping off the top section and dragging the picture outwards. Any better?

Comment: I think this is a good solution. Thanks for the help, Valorum.

Answer (score 7):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting

Answer (score 7):

[image: Westeros.org: The "A Song of Ice and Fire" Domain]

Comment: The image isn't the correct size (*"The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI"*)

Comment: @Valorum Ooops. Fixed now.

Comment: You might consider using a more appropriate font; http://www.fonts4free.net/game-of-thrones-font.html

Comment: @Valorum you should consider a proper canon.

Answer (score 7):

[image: Movies & TV Stack Exchange]

Comment: I think they also have some scifi and fantasy questions there... ;)

Comment: The colour scheme on this advert hurts my eyes.

Answer (score 6):

[image: Memory Alpha - Star Trek Canon Wiki]

Comment: New design for 2018

Answer (score 5):

[image: Find canon Star Wars information]

Comment: Why is this an ad? The Star Wars Databank is not a helpful resource. I'd rather we link to wookieepedia or something, but that one is getting voted down.

Comment: The Databank is considered a canon source of Star Wars information. A few minutes glancing through it would undoubtedly provoke new questions ("*interesting articles or findings for the curious"*)

Comment: New(ish) design for 2018

Comment: @amflare - We need to make our minds up. At least one user is downvoting wookieepedia because they'd rather have the Databank.

Comment: I mean, what's the standard we are go for? Canonicity? Then we should use the DB. Something that is interesting for new people who are not necessarily SW nerds like us, than we should go with wookieepedia

Comment: @amflare - I think we should have adverts for site that people will find interesting and that'll provoke new questions. Both the Databank and Wookieepedia meet that criteria

Answer (score 4):

[image: Questions about writing your novels, fanfic, screenplays, and more? Come to Writing.SE!]

Answer (score 3):

[image: TV Tropes will ruin your life]

Comment: No warning sign? ;-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor - I don't know if it's my browser but I don't see the tooltip come up with I hover over the picture. It should say "*TV Tropes will ruin your life*"

Comment: @Valorum I don't see it either....

Answer (score 2):

[image: Tower of Babel with SE colours.]

Comment: I don't understand this advert

Comment: How so? It's an advert for CLSE

Comment: @Valorum it seems to be a clever redesign of the [Constructed Languages Community flag](https://conlang.org/conlang_flag.svg) although what the two words mean I have no idea, I'd guess language and constructed in some language that was constructed.

Answer (score 1):

[image: The Great Outdoors Stack Exchange]

Comment: You might want to indicate that this is an SE site. Something like this; https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pOJh.png

Comment: This picture exceeds the maximum file size of 150KB

Comment: @Valorum I fixed that. It took me under a minute (download, reupload, compress, download, reupload) using [this site](https://tinypng.com/).

Comment: @Randal'Thor - I'm not overkeen to edit other people's adverts

Comment: While the ad looks really good in itself, this feels a little...disconnected from the science-fiction and fantasy community. You might want to indicate *why* this advert is of interest to the users of this site since that isn't immediately apparent. There's certainly room for ads to quite unrelated sites, but then the ad itself could work on adressing the specific community a little more.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Pottermore - The digital heart of the Wizarding World]

Comment: May as well promote buzzfeed too, seeing the direction Pottermore is taking these days...

Comment: New design for 2018.

Comment: Are downvoters not happy with pottermore or not happy with the design?

Comment: Neutral about the design. Unhappy with Pottermore. Maybe link directly to the "writings by jk rowling" section?

Comment: @ibid - What do you think?
 https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11724/20774

Answer (score 0):

[image: Wookieepedia - The Star Wars Wiki]

Comment: Do we not like wookieepedia any more?

Comment: I downvoted this for the same reason as last time: it's a non-canon source, and I at least have been told off when using it to support answers. What about SW Databank instead? (OTOH, you're obviously more of a SW expert than me ...)

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Like all wikis, there are footnotes indicating the canonicity of the sources used to generate the article. The Databank is *also* a useful source but extremely limited in scope.

Comment: If you make an ad for the HP Wikia, I'll unleash Slytherincess on you :-P

Comment: SW wikia has also been a much better source than HP wikia. This is known.

Comment: Design updated for 2018

Answer (score -1):

[image: Original Writing by J.K. Rowling]

Comment: Ibid got to you then?

Comment: No content on The Casual Vacancy in the link. Seems misleading.

Comment: Wait ... isn't that an older version of Donna Noble?

Answer (score -7):

[image: the #1 Harry Potter Fan Database]

Comment: No love for the HP Wikia?

Comment: Booooooooooooooo.