# There is now a conlang stackexchange in public beta

Tags: discussion, language

I was dragged to this site by hot network question concerning one of Tolkien's Elvish languages. I just want to bring to note that there is now a dedicated conlang site in public beta  at https://conlang.stackexchange.com/.

I don't think that this site will make questions about artificial languages (or artlangs) used in science fiction and fantasy off-topic here, it is just another option where to ask such questions.

Comment: Yep, it definitely won't affect topicality considerations for this site. It's a good resource for SFF people to know about though. Please consider making a [Community Ad](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11670/31394) for Conlang.SE, which will get more attention than this separate meta.

Comment: If it takes off, we might have a review of whether to keep them on-topic here.

Comment: Why? We don't just make all movies and tv related questions off-topic because there's a stack that covers them. Nor do that with manga/anime. Something being better suited elsewhere has no bearing on whether it's on topic here.

Comment: @Valorum: I would be kind of annoyed if we did that.  I certainly don't want to see our scope narrow to "Everything to do with SFF, unless it happens to intersect with [Gaming.SE], or [Anime.SE], or [Literature.SE], or..."

Comment: @Kevin - Honestly I'm not in the least bit invested in questions about spoken Klingon **other than the very narrow perspective of how it applies to the show**. The same goes for Tolkien's various made up languages. If ConLang is a success, I honestly think we'd do better to shove all of that over to them.

Comment: @Valorum: So use the tag filter?

Comment: @Kevin - I'd rather change the scope :-)

Comment: @Valorum: I'm a bit perturbed that your thought process sounds like "SFF's scope should exactly match the things that I personally like to answer."  I'm sure that's not what you meant to say, but would you mind providing an actual rationale for this scope change?

Comment: @Kevin - It's more that I don't think that ConLangs are an especially good match in the first place.

Comment: I don't see why questions about how Elvish works should be any less on-topic than questions about how the Floo Network works.

Comment: @MissMonicaE our resident super-user likes the clickbait questions that give him the little green +10s ;-). The HNQ can only find _so_ much interest in the history of Elvish languages.

Answer (score 12):

This isn't really a question and thus can't be "answered" as such, so I thought I'd distill some useful advice from the comments instead.

Conlangs which arise from SFF-related works are on-topic on SFF.SE, while conlangs which arise from other settings, and the construction of new conlangs, are both off-topic here.  This was true before Conlang.SE existed, and it is still true now.  Adding a new Stack doesn't change anything.  However, some questions may get better answers there than here, and *vice-versa*.  For example:

- Some conlangs have fantastical (magical) properties, and those properties are likely to be off-topic on Conlang.SE because they simply don't exist in the real world.  So you should ask about such things on SFF.SE instead.
- Some writers, like Tolkien, spend a lot of time thinking about the history of their conlangs.  Determining the in-universe etymology of words is likely to be on-topic on both sites, I *think* (it seems like Conlang.SE is still determining its scope).  However, SFF.SE is probably better positioned for questions relating to the in-universe culture and history, while Conlang.SE is probably more able to talk about linguistic processes.  You may get materially different answers as a result.
- If you want to ask a deep technical question about the linguistics of a conlang, such as "Is Elvish [nominative-accusative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominative%E2%80%93accusative_language) or [ergative-absolutive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergative%E2%80%93absolutive_language)?", that is *probably* on-topic on SFF.SE, but you are far more likely to get a useful answer from Conlang.SE or maybe even Linguistics.SE.  On any site, you should show your attempt to solve a question like that and describe in detail the part that has you confused, because otherwise it's just trivia.

Comment: Good answer. It's useful to remember that although questions can be *on-topic* on multiple sites (and therefore shouldn't be closed or migrated), one site can still be a *better* fit than another, depending on the specific type of question.